# I want to remove the string from the list which contains '!' character but after running this code I noticed that it skips the next string in the list

Tags: python

This code skips the next string in the list after it encounters an '!' in the present string.

```py
a = ["Hey! How are you?", "Wonderful drawing", "Its good", "No Idea"]      

for i in a:                 
    print(i)
    for j in i: 
        print(j)                
        if '!' in j:
            a.remove(i)
    
print(a)
```

Comment: Don't remove items from the list you are iterating over!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one liner

```
a=[s for s in a if '!' not in s]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.search()` :

```
import re
li_ = [x for x in a if not re.search("!", x)]
```